# Making metal music without real instruments

Tags: plug-ins, metal, virtual-instruments

I am searching for software that can be used to make metal music.

Is there anything good?! Doesn't matter if it is paid or free software.

Comment: You want to record a whole band, or just compose music by yourself?

Answer (score 1):

**Drums**

- [Superior Drummer 2 w. Metal Foundry SDX expansion](https://www.toontrack.com/product/the-metal-foundry-sdx/)
- [Shreddage Drums](https://impactsoundworks.com/products/category/drums-percussion/)

**Guitar and Bass**

- [Shreddage 2](https://impactsoundworks.com/products/category/guitar-bass/) - The shreddage plugins are at the moment the only decent solutions (IMO):

Take a look at [this summary](http://getinstrumental.com/best-bass-vst-plugins/) for other alternatives.

**Synths**

There are soo many. I'd invest my time in something [Kontakt/Komplete](https://www.native-instruments.com/en/products/komplete/samplers/kontakt-5/) related for the sake of simplifying the learning curve a bit.

Comment: +1 For Superior. I have the entire collection & it is simply stunning. A beginner or someone on a lower budget might want to take a look at their [EZDrummer](http://www.toontrack.com/ezdrummer-line/) alternative, though.